# Problems in installing Laravel at localhost

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I am trying to install PHP-Laravel in Windows 8 and I am using Xamp server(localhost). I am following [Installing Laravel](http://daylerees.com/2012/03/25/laravel-getting-started/) guide.
According to this guide I am making  virtual host using following code :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/TssApp/public"
 ServerName TssApp
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/TssApp/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

//Where "C:/xampp/htdocs/TssApp/public" is path of Laravel public folder
```

and I have also added following line in in etc/hosts

```
  127.0.0.2             TssApp
```

After doing necessary steps mentioned in this tutorial  when I type ***"http://TssApp"*** , it always redirect to ***"http://tssapp/xampp/"*** instead of Laravel Home page. I don't know if I am missing any thing.

**Note:** I can access laravel home page at **"http://localhost/tssapp/public/"** but want 
to use ***"http://TssApp"*** link to access my application.

Please help me regarding this issue.
Thanks .

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache? If yes and it still doesn't work make sure you're editing the correct virtual hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `NameVirtualHost *` in your virtual-hosts configuration?

You'll need to restart Apache after any changes to either /etc/hosts or your virtual-hosts configuration files

Comment: Thanks Josh, Can you tell me specifically where to add NameVirtualHost * ? Are you referring to above file where I have created virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code to C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf instead of adding it to your own conf file. As far as I know xampp will ignore it unless its in the vhosts file.

You could try this.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\TssApp\public"
ServerName tssapp
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\TssApp\public">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Although you should put your files in the xampp directory and not the htdocs directory, so your files should be C:\xampp\TssApp\public, This would stop people from visiting htdocs which is a public folder and getting access to your application.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation (that you point to), you should write

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2>
```

and not

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Could you try that and restart your computer/server?

Answer (score -1):

Add in:

```
Allow from all
```

after

```
AllowOverride all
```

The end result should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/TssApp/public"
    ServerName TssApp
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/TssApp/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure you are editing the file "httpd-vhosts.conf" found in:

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
```